# How to create computed with properties Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have 5 objects in API. I want to compare them on a computed way and then use it in the layout. I am getting an error that the type cannot be boolean and the property `isAllProperty` is unknown

```
isAllProperty (): boolean {
   let fullProperty = this.property1.name || this.property2.name || this.property3.name || this.property4.name || this.property5.name;
      return isAllStack;
    }
```

Comment: Try removing that "boolean" from your method declaration and returning `fullProperty` instead of `isAllStack`, that should be enough.

Comment: no is necessary : boolean
isAllProperty () {
   let fullProperty = this.property1.name || this.property2.name || this.property3.name || this.property4.name || this.property5.name;

      return isAllStack;
    }

Comment: if you can send the whole code.

Comment: Perhaps `return !!fullProperty`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is a bit wrong try it like this

```
  isAllProperty: function () {
     let fullProperty = this.property1.name || 
     this.property2.name || this.property3.name || 
     this.property4.name || this.property5.name;

     return isAllStack;
}
```